# How can I delete a wrong answer that I've posted?

Tags: discussion

When I realize an answer of mine was totally wrong,  what should I do?
I tried to delete it but I couldn't find any way, and I just can't edit the answer.

Should I vote for removing that post (my answer)?

Comment: It really makes me wonder why you didn't just try to click "edit" or "delete"?

Comment: @slhck in the tooltip is writen **vote to delete** not **delete** . I didn't know I must vote to delete my answer!

Comment: Ah, okay. Yeah, that only applies to users above 20000 reputation. Don't know why that says "vote" when it instantly deletes. Maybe this should be fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried clicking this:

[image]

But preventing is better than solving, so its better to not post an inaccurate answer in the first place. Which is why its always a good idea to verify your answer before posting it, if there's no source to verify it with, perhaps you shouldn't be posting it in the first place

Comment: I thought it is voting for delete not deleting. thanks a lot

Comment: @hamed - it is voting to delete - but as the post owner you have a binding vote.